# I can't find tables of postgresql in hibernate tools

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I'm using Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2), x86, and the java version is 32-bit, postgresql version is 9.6. I successfully configured the Postgresql 9.6 (64) connection through **Hibernate Configuration File (cfg.xml)** and **Hibernate Reverse Engineering File (reverng.xml)** and passed the test, but I don't always show any tables in the **Hibernate Reverse Engineering File (reveng.xml)** configuration. Refresh also does not show, excuse me did I miss something?
The following code is the contents of the hibernate.cfg.xml document.did anyone can help me,thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="RcCloud">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgresql</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/RcCloud</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">RcCloud</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: it might be my lack of knowledge but I don't understand your problem.

Comment: I found another way to solve this problem. Thank you for your attention.